# WordPress - Display children category on page

Tags: wordpress, parent, children

I have a category list from A - Z. These categories are displayed on a page. When someone clicks on ex: "A": i want them to see all the children categories which are in "A". Is there a method of showing all these children categories?

Because at the moment it will show all the posts which are in the parent "A", instead of showing all the children categories.

Example:

A:
-A1
-A2
-A3
B:
-B1
-B2
-B3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the wp_list_categories() function will return a list of all categories.

You can filter the child categories using the 'depth' parameter:

- 0 - All Categories and child Categories (Default).
- -1 - All Categories displayed in flat (no indent) form (overrides hierarchical).
- 1 - Show only top level Categories
- n - Value of n
  (some number) specifies the depth (or level) to descend in displaying
  Categories

All the info is in the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

You can then use javascript to show/hide the child lists when a user clicks its parent list item.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, just another quick question. How do i display the current category? When people decide to click on "A", i want the website to show only the child categories from "A". Is it something like this?

<?php wp_list_categories("current-cat=1&depth=1"); ?>

??

Comment: I found the solution, i only had to add this:

$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);

Comment: But now once i click on the child category, that one does not show the posts in it, it wants to show the categories in it. How can i let it display the posts in it? Do i have to create a new .php file or something? Please help